# Ruby on Rails--　リンクの設定について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

初心者なので、すごく簡単な質問をしているのかもしてませんが、、、
困って質問してみました。

rails でブログを作成中です。
article　CRUD処理などの設定はできたのですがリンクの設定に困っています。

例えば、
【　localhost---/articles/１　】
の記事（url）に直接アクセスできるリンクを作りたい時はどのようにすれば上手くいくでしょうか？？

Comment: 具体的にうまく書けてないソースコードの部分であるとか、できない部分やでてきてしまうエラーの内容などがあったらその情報を質問に追加してみてもらえませんか？今のままだと質問の内容によくわからない部分があるので、答えることが難しくなっています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状の実装などがよくわかりませんが、 `localhost:3000/articles/:id` のリンクであれば以下のように `link_to` で実現できると思います。

`<%= link_to '詳細', articles_path(@article) %>`